# Increase bid for all adgroups using adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

I would like to automate a process that can be done through the adwords admin management panel.

I have a large number of adwords campaigns, and I would like to automate the process of bidding up and down across all ad groups.

In the UI, you can do this by clicking all ad groups > Edit > Change Bids > Increase by amount (see screenshot).

Can this be done through the adwords API? Which service would I use?

[image: increase bids example]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Ad Group Service in the old Google AdWords API.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but after reading through the API doc I'm not seeing what I would use to increase the bid by a set amount.

Comment: Here's how I'd handle it. Download a report containing ad group bids and ad group ids. Loop through the report and use the BiddingStrategyConfiguration to set the CPA bid to existing bid + increased amount.